# 1920 x 1080 Splash

Tags: plymouth

I have recently purchased a 1920 x 1080 screen and the splash screen is all askew at startup and shut down. Is there a way I can fix this to suit my resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/default/grub` file and add the following line:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1920x1080x32
```

For Example:

```
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1920x1080x32
```

Don't forget to set the right `vbe` mode. Then update GRUB with `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: How might I set the vbe mode?

Comment: Install hwinfo and run sudo hwinfo --framebuffer.