# Plymouth splash screen different boot than shutdown

Tags: plymouth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [1920 x 1080 Splash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21325/1920-x-1080-splash)

The Plymouth boot splash screen is off center, although the shut-down one works as i set it (not original).

why are my boot Plymouth and shut-down Plymouths different

Answer (score 0):

You have to Press Alt + f2 and paste

```
gksu update-initramfs -c -k all
```